# Indexing error in solr:Bad Request

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I am using solr in my spring mvc project:

Here is the related code:

My configuration:

```
<bean id="solrServer" class="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:8180/sorl"/>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="1000"/>
        <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="32"/>
        <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="128"/>
</bean>
```

My domain:

```
...
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name="MySubject")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class MySubject extends BaseObject
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field("type")
    private String type;
.....
```

Indexing code:

```
try {
            solrServer.addBean(subject);
            solrServer.commit();
        } catch (IOException | SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I got exception:

```
Bad Request

request: http://localhost:8180/sorl/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:121)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.addBean(SolrServer.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.addBean(SolrServer.java:131)
```

In solr server, the log is :

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=null] unknown field 'type'
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:340)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:79)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1815)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Please kindly help me out.

Comment: You dont seem to have a `type` field in schema

Comment: Is the Content Root correct ? Shouldn't it be `solr` and not `sorl`

Comment: @aitchnyu I have "type" field in my domain class.

Comment: @Jayendra That's ok. Spell error when configuring solr server. I can access the server using http://localhost:8180/sorl

Comment: please post your schema and config

Comment: @Jayendra I use the default schema, do I have to change it? what else should I do ?

Comment: The default schema doesn't have the field type defined. Check for the fields defined in schema xml which begin with field element. Posting schema would help. e.g. '<field name="type" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"/>'